# Code for a HP-35 calculator basic functions

Tags: c++

Hi I am having some trouble implementing basic functions for a calculator of type HP-35 I am a beginner and I am having a lot of trouble with putting code together, the basic functions are the Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication and Division that I need help with.

Below is my main file:

```
/* 
* File:   main.cpp
* Author: Brenton
*
* Created on 20 September 2013, 12:10 AM
*/

#include <cstdlib>
#include "HPStack.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

/*
* 
*/
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
HPStack stack;
string line;
while (getline(cin, line)) {
stringstream expression(line);

string token;

while (expression >> token) {
if (isdigit(token[0])) {
stack.push(atof(token.data()));

//From here I am having trouble, I don't know what the code is.

} else if (token == "+") { // Addition code

} else if (token == "-") { // Subtraction code

} else if (token == "/") { // Division code

} else if (token == "*") { // Multiplication code

double x = stack.pop();
double y = stack.pop();
stack.push(y + x);
}
}
cout << stack.peek();
}
return 0;
}
```

Below is the code so far for the stack that I've created:

```
/* 
* File:   HPStack.cpp
* Author: Brenton
* 
* Created on 20 September 2013, 12:07 AM
*/

#include "HPStack.h"

HPStack::HPStack() {
}

HPStack::HPStack(const HPStack& orig) {
}

HPStack::~HPStack() {
}
```

Below is my code for the header file:

```
/* 
* File:   HPStack.h
* Author: Brenton
*
* Created on 20 September 2013, 12:10 AM
*/

#ifndef HPSTACK_H
#define HPSTACK_H

class HPStack {
public:
HPStack();
void push(double);
double pop();


private:
double stack;
double x, y, z, t;

};

#endif /* HPSTACK_H */
```

I know that this seems like a dumb question to be asking, but I really haven't got a clue what I'm really doing with the mathematics code, but I'm trying.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is a really generic question, but the assuming the HP35 is an RPN calculator then the addition code would simply pop two values off the stack, add them together, and then push the result back onto the stack. The subtraction function would be similar, just make sure that you subtract them in the correct order.

You obviously need to finish implementing your stack also. If you are using C++ and you don't plan to add extra functionality, then just use `std::stack<double>` instead.

From looking at wikipedia, it doesn't appear that it is RPN calculator. I think you must be trying to handle operator precedence perhaps?

Comment: I'm just really confused about what the addition code is besides the obvious "+" symbol, & I don't really know how to use the pop & push functions I am just guessing at the moment

Comment: The "+" symbol is probably what you want actually. So, the code would be something like `stack.push(stack.pop() + stack.pop());` Subtraction is slightly more difficult as I alluded to above.

Comment: @Brenton: if this indeed is meant to be an RPN calculator, you can follow the example on [wikipedia on RPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation): pop 2 numbers, add, push result back. Do the same for other operators; if the input was correct, you will end up with a stack containing just the result.

Answer (score 0):

This might not fully answer your question but might give you the rough outline, by working through an example.

**original expression** :

```
( ( 1 + 2) * 3 ) + 4 )
```

**tree representation** :

```
      +
     / \
    *   4
   / \
  +   3
 / \
1   2
```

**stack representation** (pushing / popping from the top) :

```
1
2
+
3
*
4
+
```

**Processing the stack** :

you can process this stack step by step.  The aim is to reduce the stack to a single value which is the answer.  On each step you inspect the three values from the top of the stack - top two should be numerical values, the third should be an operator to apply to the two.

Step 1 : replace 1,2,+ with 3, which leaves stack as :

```
3
3
*
4
+
```

Step 2 : replace 3,3,* with 9, which leaves stack as :

```
9
4
+
```

Step 3 : replace 9.,4,+ with 13.  Since the stack has just one value on it, that is the answer.

So, that shows how the stack representation should look, and how to process the stack to get an answer.  It doesn't show how to parse the text expression in order to set up the stack initially (I don't know that bit!).

Comment: apparently this approach can put it into the correct Reverse Polish Notation form to go on the stack : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm